# Laravel with MSSQL not returning fractional seconds (no milliseconds)

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, datetime

I am connecting to an existing database using Laravel 8, SQL Server 2019 and existing Stored Procedures.  There are numerous `datetime` fields stored in various tables which include fractional seconds (`Y-m-d H:m:s.v`), however, when I export this data through Laravel, I get no milliseconds.  Even running the results through `dd()` still doesn't include the milliseconds.

From Database:

[image]

dd():
[image]

Even running a basic `select *` on the tables isn't returning the milliseconds either.

Is there anyway I can overcome this as I need reference to the full date and time value.

**Updated Information**

```
Laravel Version: 8.9.0
Homestead Version: 9.5.1
Vagrant Version: 2.2.9
PHP Version: 7.4.5
MSSQL Version: 2019
```

Running the following raw query from the DB:

```
$q = WarehouseCredit::select(DB::raw(
    InvoiceNumber,
    DateModified,
    CONVERT(varchar, DateModified, 121) AS DateModified1"
))
```

Returns

```
[
  {
    "InvoiceNumber": "A00001",
    "DateModified": "2020-03-04 09:58:56",
    "DateModified1": "2020-03-04 09:58:56.723"
  }
],
```

I don't understand why the only way I can retrieve the fractional seconds is to convert the field to a string.  This isn't the preferred method for me as I will eventually be retrieving the information via Stored Procedure so I won't have the ability to run raw queries.

I can't find any information around other people experiencing this issue to the same extent, so I can't tell if this is a PHP, Laravel, MSSQL, Linux or Homestead issue, or a combination of multiple.

If anyone at all could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give the code of stored procedure

Comment: Sorry @MuhammadWaqasAziz I have just determined that even just running a simple `select *` statement from the table is still dropping milliseconds.  So it doesn't seem related to the Stored Procedure like I thought.

Comment: Laravel runs on top of PHP, doesn't it? Does the PHP DateTime class support milliseconds?

Comment: Have you found the solution after time? @Riples

Comment: @PsychoX No, no solution.  I find this strange that no one has ever come across this.  My ONLY option was to ask the DB administrator to add an additional field to the DB to `cast` the field into the correct format - to which he wasn't happy about, but had no choice.  Really disappointing outcome for me as this shouldn't be rocket science.